# XSLT - Insert element at a position based on value of another element at same level

Tags: xslt, insert, position, conditional-statements, element

```
<Level>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Number>456</Number>
    <DateTime>2020-03-11T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
<Level>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <DateTime>2020-03-13T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
 <Level>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    <Number>789</Number>
    <DateTime>2020-03-12T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
```

Insert a new element Value below the element  only when Level/Name = ABC

So that result should be as follows:

```
 <Level>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Number>456</Number>
    <DateTime>2020-03-11T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
<Level>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Number>123</Number>
    <Type>Value</Type>
    <DateTime>2020-03-13T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
 <Level>
    <Name>PQR</Name>
    <Number>789</Number>
    <DateTime>2020-03-12T08:53:00</DateTime>
 </Level>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be inserted below <Number> tag only

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: michael.hor257k, Got you. Perhaps, i should have provided what I tried. I was either able to create an element below the <Number> of every Level tag or under Name='ABC', but not create the tag under <Number> only when Name='ABC'.

Comment: I have tried these two tags to match: <xsl:template match="Number"> 
 <xsl:template match="Name[contains(.,'ABC')]" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Level/Number[../Name='ABC']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Type>Value</Type>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mN/1

Comment: Thank you Sebastien. It worked like a charm. I tried <xsl:template match="Number"> <xsl:template match="Name[contains(.,'ABC')]" >, but couldn't combine them both.